# How to set search sizelimit in openLDAP 2.4.43-x86

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is there a way to set the search sizelimit in openLDAP? I am using openLDAP2.4.43-x86 . But when i am searching its gives me all the records which i have in my ldap( i have 750000 users). I tried with several option by setting sizelimit/olcSizeLimit in `slapd.conf` file as well as by adding this

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSizeLimit
olcSizeLimit: 500
```

and running through cmd prompt.but no luck. Any help on this?

Comment: Yes, see the [man page](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.3-Release&format=html). Off topic.

Comment: thanks EJP.. even i tried this options as well sizelimit 500 but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a file limits.ldif

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcLimits
olcLimits: dn.exact="uid=youruser,dc=xxxx,dc=xxxx" time.soft=unlimited time.hard=unlimited size.soft=unlimited size.hard=unlimited
```

Then execute:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f limits.ldif
```